# Reference Component Microsoft.CSharp could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reference, components

I found this problem on my C# project which I started at Visual Studio 2010, when I go to another PC I use in 2008, I open the project.csproj:

> A get or set accessor expected

and warning:

> The referenced component 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found.

I thought that it was about .NET Framework or Microsoft.CSharp is not located, because it says that:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.CSharp". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors

but I'm not sure about the problem, can you guys give me a solution? Really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are targeting .NET 4.0 in the project, and then trying to load it in VS2008 which only targets up to .NET 3.5.

If you **need** to use the project in VS2008, then you should re-target the project at .NET 3.5:

[image]

and then remove any incorrect references (they'll probably have yellow warning triangles on them anyway).

The `A get or set accessor expected` also suggests you're using new C# syntax, for example `dynamic`. If you need to target older C# compilers, you'll have to *not do that*. If you are using multiple IDE versions and it is being a problem, then to ensure you don't do that accidentally you can set the language version for the project via Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced:

[image]

Comment: hmmm your right.. :) i removed it, hmmm another problem iv'e discover
`A get or set accessor expected`

when i try to declare a string.... :/

Comment: @mardagz you'll have to show the exact code you're using for me to comment on that

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/32229605/screenshot%20-%20hp/this.png

here's screenshot

Comment: @mardagz that isn't valid on *any* C# compiler - is that meant to be a method? if so it needs parenthesis, i.e. `public void SelectPatient() {...}`

Comment: @mardagz in VS2008 that is correct, because to VS2008 "C# 3.0" is the same as "default". That window is useful if you are still also using the project in VS2010, to stop you from accidentally using language features that only exist in VS2010

Comment: in my language version only show ISO1, ISO2in my language version only show ISO1, ISO2owhh crap :D  hahaha. almost forgot :/ hahaha thanks you so much @Marc, anyway if don't mind, are you using windows8?

Comment: @mardagz don't worry about the language version unless you're also using VS2010 and you keep getting hurt by using new language features. And yes, I'm on win8

Comment: :) yes im new in c# just a week ago :D hihii, i supposedly using vb for this project but i challenge my self using c# :D whew... 

wow i love the features in windows 8 :D